# Use date command within awk arguments

Tags: shell, date, awk

I've a file that looks like this

```
server1-adm.test.com,/var,dir,29987,2007-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server2.fs.com,/DATA_File.out,file,299076487,2008-10-15 05:12:23,user1,group1
server3-prd.mod.com,/opt,dir,29987,2009-05-03 00:13:23,user1,group1
server4,/var/tmp/xxz.zip,file,400,2007-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server1-adm.test.com,/usr,dir,34299876,2006-12-03 16:52:43,root,root
server3-prd.mod.com,/local/home,dir,400,2009-05-03 12:13:23,user2,group1
```

The 5th column is `date + time` value that I want to modify. I tried using multiple awk statements together, but it looked too confusing, prone to mistakes. 
Instead of using multiple statements to do date format conversion, how can I use the `date` system command within awk to convert to below results.

```
server1-adm.test.com,/var,dir,29987,2007-12-03 03:52:43 PM,root,root
server2.fs.com,/DATA_File.out,file,299076487,2008-10-15 05:12:23 AM,user1,group1
server3-prd.mod.com,/opt,dir,29987,2009-05-03 00:13:23 AM,user1,group1
server4,/var/tmp/xxz.zip,file,400,2007-12-03 03:52:43 PM,root,root
server1-adm.test.com,/usr,dir,34299876,2006-12-03 04:52:43 PM,root,root
server3-prd.mod.com,/local/home,dir,400,2009-05-03 12:13:23 PM,user2,group1
```

Something in lines of `date -d "2007-12-03 15:52:43" +%Y/%m/%d:%H%M%S`. I don't know how we can get AM/PM in `date` command.

I already have multiple awk statements running together as part of a script to perform other text modification on the same incoming file, so I would like to use an awk + date statement to do it.

Comment: @Ed Morton, GNU awk as in gawk? Yes, the system has gawk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use GNU `awk`, it provides some time functions that would make your program run muuuuch faster than calling your shell + `date` for each line of your CSV file:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } { gsub("[-:]", " ", $5); $5 = strftime("%F %r", mktime($5)) } 1'
```

Expanded form:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

    {
        gsub("[-:]", " ", $5)
        $5 = strftime("%F %r", mktime($5))
    }

    1
'
```

---

If you really want to use an external `date` command, as you state in your question, then use GNU `awk` co-processes so that only one `date` command is started and reused at each line:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","; cmd = "stdbuf -oL date -f - +%F\" \"%r" } { print $5 |& cmd; cmd |& getline $5 } 1'
```

Expanded form:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ","
        cmd = "stdbuf -oL date -f - +%F\" \"%r"
    }

    {
        print $5 |& cmd
        cmd |& getline $5
    }

    1
'
```

But you really ought to go with the first solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll stick to the GNU awk time function.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '{split($6,array,":");$6=array[1]>12?sprintf("%02d",array[1]-12)":"array[2]":"array[3]" PM":(array[1]==12?$6 " PM":$6 " AM")} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too here for above code.

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '                                                         ##Making field separator as space and comma for all the lines of Input_file.
{
  split($6,array,":")                                                  ##using split function to split 6th field of current line by making : as field sep for it.
  $6=array[1]>12?sprintf("%02d",array[1]-12)":"array[2]":"array[3]" PM" :$6 " AM" ##re-creating $6 value by checking condition if its 1st value array value which is time is greater than 12 than subtracting its value with 12 here and adding PM and AM according to it too.
}
1                                                                      ##Mentioning 1 will print the edited/non-edited value of line.
' Input_file                                                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I've already used multiple awk statements to convert the date-time to desired value, but I'm looking for a shorter way using `date` system command in awk.

Comment: @Marcos, did you try my one liner? That will give your correct output, please try it once and let me know then?

Comment: Yes the one-liner does work, but I'm looking for a solution where I can use `date` command to make things simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `date` command directly on the `$5` variable as below. Be careful with the quoting of the command. Here we form the command string `cmd` from the `$5` with the flags as needed with `%p` to print the appropriate `AM` or `PM` depending on time of the day.

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{cmd = "date -d \""$5"\" \"+%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p\""}{ cmd|getline D; close(cmd); $5=D}1' file
```

The crucial part is in `close(cmd)` statement. It forces `awk` to execute `cmd` each time, so, date would be actual one each time. Also see [Using `getline` into a Variable from a Pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe)

Comment: Thanks your solution works good. But then I didn't knew GNU awk had time functions, hence marking `xhienne` solution as answer, as this suits my requirements better.

Answer (score 1):

Orders is a file of csv records, each of the records having three fields: order number,due date,lead time. I wanted to calculate each order's start date by subtracting the lead time from the due date, format the result as dd-Mmm-yyyy, and append this to the original record read from orders.

```
awk -F, '{"date --date=\""$2" -"$3" day\" +%d-%b-%Y" | getline sd; print $1","$2","$3","sd}' orders
```

So, let's break it down.

-F, tells Awk to use a comma as the field separator

'{command | getline variable;command}' is what I want awk to do with each record

"date --date=""$2" -"$3" day" +%d-%b-%Y" subtracts $3 days from date $2
and formats the result as dd-Mmm-yyyy.

command | getline variable assigns the result of command to variable

print $1","$2","$3","sd prints the desired output

Here's the result

```
$ cat orders
order01,01-Mar-2024,1
order02,01-Jan-2021,2
$ awk -F, '{"date --date=\""$2" -"$3" day\" +%d-%b-%Y" | getline d; print $1","$2","$3","d}' orders
order01,01-Mar-2024,1,29-Feb-2024
order02,01-Jan-2021,2,30-Dec-2020
```